# Data doesn't display

Tags: php, laravel

Need some help here, I'm using Laravel app, my problem is my data wont display on the table. I tried some ways to display my data but it doesn't work. 
Here's my code.

```
<tbody>
    @if (count($expenses) > 0)
        @foreach ($expenses as $expense)
            <tr data-entry-id="{{ $expense->id }}">
                <td field-key='expense_category'>{{ $expense->expense_category->name or '' }}</td>
                            <td field-key='entry_date'>{{ $expense->entry_date }}</td>
                            <td field-key='amount'>{{ $expense->amount }}</td>
                            <td field-key='created_by'>{{ $expense->created_by->name or '' }}</td>
                                                            <td>
                                @can('view')
                                <a href="{{ route('expenses.show',[$expense->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">@lang('quickadmin.qa_view')</a>
                                @endcan
                                @can('edit')
                                <a href="{{ route('expenses.edit',[$expense->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">@lang('quickadmin.qa_edit')</a>
                                @endcan
                                @can('delete')
                                {!! Form::open(array(
                                    'style' => 'display: inline-block;',
                                    'method' => 'DELETE',
                                    'onsubmit' => "return confirm('".trans("quickadmin.qa_are_you_sure")."');",
                                    'route' => ['expenses.destroy', $expense->id])) !!}
                                {!! Form::submit(trans('quickadmin.qa_delete'), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger')) !!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                                @endcan
                            </td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9">@lang('quickadmin.qa_no_entries_in_table')</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
</tbody>
```

here is my expenseController.
but i have never touched this code, i always work on the table form.

```
 class ExpensesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of Expense.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('expense_access')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        if ($filterBy = Input::get('filter')) {
             if ($filterBy == 'all') {
                Session::put('Expense.filter', 'all');
             } elseif ($filterBy == 'my') {
                 Session::put('Expense.filter', 'my');
             }
         }

                $expenses = Expense::all();

        return view('admin.expenses.index', compact('expenses'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you send the data from your Controller to this view please?

Comment: @SamBellerose I edited my question and include the controller you ask.

Answer (score 0):

try to find are you getting data from DB or not ....

```
 $expenses = Expense::all();
 dd($expenses);
```

It will show your data collection.
As I Think you are not getting any data from here.

Comment: i wish to access inputted data from database with my code stated above, but it doesn't work. am I missing something? please let me know what was lack or missing.